# Enumerate over a sequence in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, enumeration

In Python I can do this:

```
animals = ['dog', 'cat', 'bird']
for i, animal in enumerate(animals):
    print i, animal
```

Which outputs:

```
0 dog
1 cat
2 bird
```

How would I accomplish the same thing in Clojure?  I considered using a list comprehension like this:

```
(println
  (let [animals ["dog" "cat" "bird"]]
    (for [i (range (count animals))
          animal animals]
      (format "%d %d\n" i animal))))
```

But this prints out every combination of number and animal.  I'm guessing there is a simple and elegant way to do this but I'm not seeing it.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

There is `map-indexed` in core as of 1.2.

Your example would be:

```
(doseq [[i animal] (map-indexed vector ["dog" "cat" "bird"])]
  (println i animal))
```

Answer (score 9):

Quick solution:

```
(let [animals ["dog", "cat", "bird"]]
  (map vector (range) animals))
```

Or, if you want to wrap it in a function:

```
(defn enum [s]
  (map vector (range) s))

(doseq [[i animal] (enum ["dog", "cat", "bird"])]
  (println i animal))
```

What happens here is the function vector is applied to each element in both sequences, and the result is collected in a lazy collection.

Go ahead, try it in your repl.

Answer (score 8):

Use indexed from [clojure.contrib.seq](http://clojure.github.com/clojure-contrib/seq-api.html#clojure.contrib.seq/indexed):

Usage: `(indexed s)`
Returns a lazy sequence of [index, item] pairs, where items come
from 's' and indexes count up from zero.

`(indexed '(a b c d))  =>  ([0 a] [1 b] [2 c] [3 d]`

For your example this is

```
(require 'clojure.contrib.seq)
(doseq [[i animal] (clojure.contrib.seq/indexed ["dog", "cat", "bird"])]
  (println i animal))
```

Comment: heh. Take a look at the source code for function indexed: https://github.com/clojure/clojure-contrib/blob/b8d2743d3a89e13fc9deb2844ca2167b34aaa9b6/src/main/clojure/clojure/contrib/seq.clj#L51

Comment: heh. I know. I wonder why you named the function 'enum' in your example, then :-)

Comment: clojure-contrib is now deprecated

Answer (score 5):

`map-indexed` looks right but: Do we really need all of the `doseq` and deconstructing args stuff in the other answers?

```
(map-indexed println ["dog", "cat", "bird"])
```

**EDIT:**
as noted by @gits this works in the REPL but doesn't respect that clojure is lazy by default. `dorun` seems to be the closest [among `doseq`, `doall` and `doseq`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25327369/what-is-the-difference-among-the-functions-doall-dorun-doseq-and-for) for this. `doseq`, howver, seems to be the idiomatic favorite here.

```
(dorun (map-indexed println ["dog", "cat", "bird"]))
```

Comment: `map-indexed` returns a lazy seq. `doseq` is necessary to ensure side effects happen now, not later (in this case, the printing effected by `println`).

Comment: @git right and thanks,  I noticed that but didn't update because I'm still learning and don't know if doseq is the real favorite idiom here.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another option is to use [`reduce-kv`](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/reduce-kv), which pairs the elements of a vector with their indexes.

Thus,

```
(reduce-kv #(println %2 %3) nil ["dog" "cat" "bird"])
```

or perhaps the slightly more explicit

```
(reduce-kv (fn [_ i animal] (println i animal)) nil ["dog" "cat" "bird"])
```

I wouldn’t pick this solution over the one with `doseq` here, but it is good to be aware of this specialisation for vectors in `reduce-kv`.