# What is the difference among the functions doall dorun doseq and for?

Tags: clojure

What is the difference between the functions `doall`, `dorun`, `doseq`, and `for` ?

I found some information scattered throughout the internet, but I think it would be better to centralize that information here.

Comment: http://onclojure.com/2009/03/04/dorun-doseq-doall/

Comment: google is your friend - https://groups.google.com/d/topic/clojure/8ebJsllH8UY/discussion

Comment: http://julianlaffey.wordpress.com/2013/04/25/untangling-clojures-do-functions-do-doall-dorun-doseq-dosync-dotimes-doto/

Comment: @edbond stack overflow is a better friend

Comment: @DaveYarwood That Wordpress site has been deleted.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! Thankfully, it's been archived: https://web.archive.org/web/20141028184354/https://julianlaffey.wordpress.com/2013/04/25/untangling-clojures-do-functions-do-doall-dorun-doseq-dosync-dotimes-doto/

Answer (score 74, accepted):

`dorun`, `doall`, and `doseq` are all for forcing lazy sequences, presumably to get side effects.

- `dorun` - don't hold whole seq in memory while forcing, return `nil`
- `doall` - hold whole seq in memory while forcing (i.e. *all* of it) and return the seq
- `doseq` - same as `dorun`, but gives you chance to do something with each element as it's forced; returns `nil`

`for` is different in that it's a list comprehension, and isn't related to forcing effects. `doseq` and `for` have the same binding syntax, which may be a source of confusion, but `doseq` always returns `nil`, and `for` returns a lazy seq.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by '`doseq` - same as `doall`, but gives you chance to do something with each element as it's forced'. Surely it's a `for`-like version of `dorun`, not of `doall`.

Comment: @Thumbnail Good catch. I've updated the answer to reflect this. Thanks!

Answer (score 26):

You can see how `dorun` and `doall` relate to one another by looking at the (simplified) source code:

```
(defn dorun [coll]
  (when (seq coll) (recur (next coll))))

(defn doall [coll] (dorun coll) coll)
```

- `dorun` runs through the sequence, forgetting it as it goes,
  ultimately returning `nil`.
- `doall` returns its sequence argument, now realised by the `dorun`.

Similarly, we could implement `doseq` in terms of `dorun` and `for`:

```
(defmacro doseq [seq-exprs & body]
  `(dorun (for ~seq-exprs ~@body)))
```

For some reason, performance perhaps, this is not done. The standard `doseq` is written out in full, imitating `for`.